# how to set background in JPanel

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

class DisplayArea extends JPanel {
    private Color c;
    public static final int DISPLAY_SIZE = 500;

    public DisplayArea() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(DISPLAY_SIZE, DISPLAY_SIZE);
    }
}
```

why does it say "cannot find symbol" at"setBackground(Color.white)"

Comment: This should work. Please edit your question and post the full and complete error message for us. You don't have your own class named JPanel, do you?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reminder. I  correct

Comment: Works for me, you're probably going to want to make sure you don't have any old classes laying around when you build it